# How to combine multiple pages from a website into one data frame in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

**Desired**

I want to capture all the winners and their opponents from the ibjjf website. This includes details like their division, belt color, gym, rank, etc. I'm doing this by scraping the branches from within each link on [this page](https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/), and putting it into a dataframe. Before creating a loop, I scraped one page to test out the code I wrote, and it worked exactly as I wanted it to.

This is what the end data frame should look like:

[image: Original Data Frame]

**Problems**

I created a loop to capture this information from multiple pages. The division, belt, gender, and weight all only appear once on each page. However, when I ran my code on just one page, r automatically filled in the correct information for each competitor. I would like it to automatically fill in the appropriate information for all pages. For example, if the belt color is Black, I want r to fill in black next to each competitor name that appears on that page. Just like in the photo.

Here is a sample of the code I wrote for the loop:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# CREATE EMPTY VECTORS ---------------------------------------
# fight info vectors
division_all = c()
gender_all = c()
belt_all = c()
weight_all = c()
fightAndMat_all = c()
date_all = c()
competitor_all = c()
name_all = c()
gym_all = c()

# Create for loop -----------------------------------
for (i in 46:70){
  MensUrl <- read_html(paste0('https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/20531', i))

# SCRAPE THE DATA #############################################
## SCRAPE FIGHT INFO -------------------------------------------
# fight info
division <- MensUrl %>% 
  html_nodes('.category-title__age-division') %>% 
  html_text()

gender <- MensUrl %>% 
  html_nodes('.category-title__age-division+ .category-title__label') %>% 
  html_text()

belt <- MensUrl %>% 
  html_nodes('.category-title__label:nth-child(3)') %>% 
  html_text()

weight <-  MensUrl %>% 
  html_nodes('.category-title__label:nth-child(4)') %>% 
  html_text()

fightAndMat <- MensUrl %>% 
  html_nodes('.bracket-match-header__where , .bracket-match-header__fight') %>% 
  html_text()

date = MensUrl %>% 
  html_nodes('.bracket-match-header__when') %>% 
  html_text()

competitor = MensUrl %>% 
  html_nodes('.match-card__competitor-n') %>% 
  html_text()

name = MensUrl %>% 
  html_nodes('.match-card__competitor-name') %>% 
  html_text()

gym = MensUrl %>% 
  html_nodes('.match-card__club-name') %>% 
  html_text()

# append fight info ----

division_all = append(division_all,division)
gender_all = append(gender_all,gender)
belt_all = append(belt_all,belt)
weight_all = append(weight_all, weight)
fightAndMat_all = append(fightAndMat_all, fightAndMat)
date_all = append(date_all,date)
competitor_all = append(competitor_all,competitor)
name_all = append(name_all,name)
gym_all = append(gym_all, gym)
}

# CONVERT TO DATA FRAMES --------------------------------------------------

#### create match df ####
matches = data.frame('division' = division_all,
                     'gender' = gender_all,
                     'belt' = belt_all,
                     'weight' = weight_all,
                     'fightAndMat' = fightAndMat_all,
                     'date' = date_all,
                     'competitor' = competitor_all,
                     'name' = name_all,
                     'gym' = gym_all)

> Error in data.frame(division = division_all, gender = gender_all, belt = belt_all,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 25, 1818, 909, 2601, 2207
```

Comment: Your question is too long, it's hard to understand what you want to obtain

Comment: The columns of the `matches` dataframe have different lengths

Comment: Yes, they do. I revised the question. Hopefully that's a little clearer. Basically, I want to scrape all the competitors and include things like the division they're in. How do I get it to show this information for each competitor like in the photo I attached?

Comment: I think I get what you want you want. You'll have to use a list at some point. I'll show you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a list to store each element of an iteration.
And another list to store each list obtained.
Here is the beginning of the solution

```r
library(rvest); library(tidyverse)

# CREATE EMPTY VECTORS ---------------------------------------
# fight info vectors
division_all = gender_all = belt_all = weight_all = fightAndMat_all = date_all = competitor_all = name_all = gym_all = c()
liste_df <- vector("list", 70- 46 + 1) # Initialize a list with 70 - 46 + 1 NULL elements
l <- 1
# Create for loop -----------------------------------
for (i in 46:70){
  MensUrl <- read_html(paste0('https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/20531', i))
  
  # SCRAPE THE DATA #############################################
  ## SCRAPE FIGHT INFO -------------------------------------------
  # fight info
  division <- MensUrl %>% 
    html_nodes('.category-title__age-division') %>% 
    html_text()
  
  gender <- MensUrl %>% 
    html_nodes('.category-title__age-division+ .category-title__label') %>% 
    html_text()
  
  belt <- MensUrl %>% 
    html_nodes('.category-title__label:nth-child(3)') %>% 
    html_text()
  
  weight <-  MensUrl %>% 
    html_nodes('.category-title__label:nth-child(4)') %>% 
    html_text()
  
  fightAndMat <- MensUrl %>% 
    html_nodes('.bracket-match-header__where , .bracket-match-header__fight') %>% 
    html_text()
  
  date = MensUrl %>% 
    html_nodes('.bracket-match-header__when') %>% 
    html_text()
  
  competitor = MensUrl %>% 
    html_nodes('.match-card__competitor-n') %>% 
    html_text()
  
  name = MensUrl %>% 
    html_nodes('.match-card__competitor-name') %>% 
    html_text()
  
  gym = MensUrl %>% 
    html_nodes('.match-card__club-name') %>% 
    html_text()
  
  # THE CODE THAT IS NEW
  liste_df[[l]] <- list(division, gender, belt, weight, fightAndMat, date, competitor, name, gym) %>% 
    setNames(c("division", "gender", "belt", "weight", "fightAndMat", "date", "competitor", "name", "gym"))
  l <- l + 1
}

# WHAT TO DO NEXT?
```

A example of an element of `liste_df`:

```r
> liste_df[[1]]
$division
[1] "\nMaster 1 \n"

$gender
[1] "\n\n Male \n"

$belt
[1] "\n\n BLUE \n"

$weight
[1] "\n\n Rooster\n"

$fightAndMat
 [1] "FIGHT 30: Mat 3" "FIGHT 30:"       "FIGHT 41: Mat 3" "FIGHT 41:"      
 [5] "FIGHT 32: Mat 3" "FIGHT 32:"       "FIGHT 35: Mat 3" "FIGHT 35:"      
 [9] "FIGHT 38: Mat 3" "FIGHT 38:"       "FIGHT 31: Mat 3" "FIGHT 31:"      
[13] "FIGHT 34: Mat 3" "FIGHT 34:"      

$date
[1] "Sat 09/03 at 01:04 PM" "Sat 09/03 at 02:33 PM" "Sat 09/03 at 01:16 PM"
[4] "Sat 09/03 at 01:54 PM" "Sat 09/03 at 02:10 PM" "Sat 09/03 at 01:10 PM"
[7] "Sat 09/03 at 01:37 PM"

$competitor
 [1] "1" "8" "3" "1" "2" "7" "4" "1" "3" "7" "4" "6" "3" "5"

$name
 [1] "Anthony Garcia"             "Jonathan Ti Shih Yeung"     "Tony Thai Nguyen"          
 [4] "Anthony Garcia"             "Daniel Armando Avilez"      "Philip Paul Johns Jr"      
 [7] "Emanuel Paul Q Babala"      "Anthony Garcia"             "Tony Thai Nguyen"          
[10] "Philip Paul Johns Jr"       "Emanuel Paul Q Babala"      "Wesley Allen Morris"       
[13] "Tony Thai Nguyen"           "Daryl Charles Ayson Santos"

$gym
 [1] "American Top Team"           "Evolve MMA"                 
 [3] "CheckMat"                    "American Top Team"          
 [5] "Absolute Behring"            "Form Jiu Jitsu Academy"     
 [7] "Lansang Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu" "American Top Team"          
 [9] "CheckMat"                    "Form Jiu Jitsu Academy"     
[11] "Lansang Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu" "Roberto Traven BJJ"         
[13] "CheckMat"                    "Yemaso Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu"
```

Comment: Hi Julien, I'm trying to create a data frame of all competitors from the IBJJF website. The data frame should indicate the division, belt, gender, and other information of each competitor. The code I wrote produces a similar result to the one you have above. the issue is that when doing the loop, it does not keep track of the division, belt, weight, or gender for each person. The data frame should look like the one I have in the photo.

Comment: The problem is that the `date` and `name` vectors don't have the same length

Comment: I know. The division, belt, gender, and weight all only appear once on each page. However, when I ran my code on just one page, r automatically filled in the correct information for each competitor. I would like it to automatically fill in the appropriate information for all pages. For example, if the belt color is Black, I want r to fill in black next to each competitor name that appears on that page. Just like in the photo.

Comment: Yes when the vector is of length one, it fills automatically, but not for other cases

Comment: How would I get it to fill automatically?

Comment: The problem is that it won't fill the way that you want, probably

Comment: In your desired dataframe, you have a row fightandMat =  "FIGHT 30:" which is not present in the data from the website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247956/discussion-between-julien-and-bandcar).